# Ignoring NaN when using divide, but including available info

Tags: python, pandas, divide

I have a stock 'BHGE' in a dataframe called `start_data`, here is start_data['BHGE']:

```
2017-06-28          NaN
2017-06-29          NaN
2017-06-30    37.971771
2017-07-03    40.180004
```

And I am using this calculation to find the stocks return:

```
pct_change = start_data.iloc[-1].divide(start_data.loc[start_pct_change])-1
```

The problem is that when I run: `pct_change['BHGE']` , it returns NaN, but I would like it to return the pct change for all the values that are available.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using the percent change method includes with pandas?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
ix = ['2017-06-28','2017-06-29','2017-06-30','2017-07-03']
price = [np.NaN,np.NaN,37.971771,40.180004]
df = pd.DataFrame(price, index = ix)
df
```

[image]

```
pct_change = df.pct_change()
pct_change
```

[image]

Comment: and how would you associate the stock with just that number? While ignoring the Nan values - because I'm plotting it on a bar plot

Comment: If I understand correctly that you want to keep it all in one DataFrame, you would do: start_data['BHGE_pct_change'] = start_data['BHGE'].pct_change()

Comment: @thomas.mac if this helped you, please mark it as answered. thanks :)